# get content of a div from a variable using jQuery

Tags: jquery

i am building a php form with ajax and i am submitting the form variables to the same page where the form resides. my validating code looks like

```
if($valid){
    echo "<div id='retmsg'>Your message has been submitted successfully</div>";
}
else {
    echo "<div id='retmsg'>An error occured!</div>";
}
```

My ajax code

```
function form_submit() {
 $('#response').html('Loading...').fadeIn();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
url:  "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",
data: "title=" + $('#title').val() + "&content=" + $('#contents').val(),
success: function(html){
var message = $("#retmsg").html(html);
alert(message);
  }

}); 
}
```

i need to alert the contents of div id "retmsg". But the alert shows me like "[Object Object]". Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Check

```
var message = $("#retmsg").value;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It shows "undefined". For your information i am getting the all contents in a variable "html" and then i am trying to filter out contents of #retmsg

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 alert(message.html())
```

Comment: I suggest you to use firebug to test your client side code. I did alert($("#someExistingID").html("a").html()) in some pages and it shows me "a"... probably you are losing some error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [jquery`s html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/). if you want to retrieve the html content of a certain element you need to use html() function with no arguments.

so from this:

```
var message = $("#retmsg").html(html);
```

to this:

```
var message = $("#retmsg").html();
```

The "[Object Object]" that the

```
$("#retmsg").html(html);
```

returns is actually a jquery object. You can find more on [jquery chain](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2007/10/26/jQuery-Understanding-the-chain)

Comment: but i am submitting the form the same page and the page already has the html elements(whole page with form elements), html() will return all contents again. Hope you understand

Comment: what i want to say is that in your code, you alert the jquery object, 
to alert the the contents of div id "retmsg" as you said you need to do :
alert($("#retmsg").html());

Comment: i think both ways are same because i get the same answer for also alert($("#retmsg").html())

Comment: alert($("#retmsg")[0].innerHTML);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all gentle mens who shared my issue. As i mentioned in my description, as i submitted the form to the same page, the page loads again with all components i used such as jQuery library and js files i.e the whole document. That's the problem. I simply used if(post){  } else { form validation } for the whole html content and got it solved.